# Draw a twoport as a node with circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

Simple question: can I draw a twoport as a node using circuitikz? The manual would suggest I can using something like: `\draw (0,2) node[twoport,t=text] {};`

Context: I am drawing a block diagram and want the first block not to have an input arrow.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,leqno,openbib,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage[]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}  

\begin{figure}[!t]
    \centering
    \begin{circuitikz}[]

        % I expect this to draw a box at (0,0)
        \draw (0,0) node[twoport,t=text](start){};

        % This works
        \draw (start.east) to[twoport,t=text] (2,0);

    \end{circuitikz}

    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:MWE}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) I removed the `memoir` tag as it is not related to the actual question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Circuitikz adds "shape" to the end of every bipole name.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,leqno,openbib,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}  
\begin{figure}[!t]
    \centering
    \begin{circuitikz}[]
        % I expect this to draw a box at (0,0)
        \draw (0,0) node[twoportshape,t=text](start){};
        % This works
        \draw (start.east) to[twoport,t=text] (2,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:MWE}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Fantastic! I could not see that in the documentation but looking for it have found it in footnote 3 in section 4 of the manual.

Comment: I cheated: I just looked at the definition of `\pgfcircdeclarebipole`.